# How much do production Azure hosted add-ins cost?

Tags: provider-hosted-app, azure

After the add-in model has been in broad use for awhile, provider hosted seems to be the model of choice for SharePoint add-ins. I've never hosted one in Azure before. What are real world average monthly costs for a production, provider-hosted add-in on Azure?

Comment: that would vary greatly between your EA (if you have one), the server type you pick, and the usage.

Comment: That's also good information. Not sure everyone's aware of what EAs are and how they effect Azure. I'm not clear on that myself. Also, sounds like you prefer a server to a service like @waqas suggests in his answer. Would be open to assumptions on typical usage for this scenario based on real world experience.

Comment: Enterprise Agreements basically will give you a cut rate over what the listed retail price is. Server or service either will work, it depends on how much control you want to have. I would probably lean towards a server as you could centrally host many app services. These all play into the cost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's depends how you want to host your App. price range is from free to upto hundreds of $$$. You have to choose one of the following options

1. FREE (Try for Free)
2. SHARED(Host Basic Apps)
3. BASIC (More Features for Dev / Test)
4. STANDARD (Go Live with Web and Mobile)
5. PREMIUM

Here is comparison between above options: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

Now you can go to the Azure Pricing calculator to estimate the price. [On this Page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) Click Add > Click Feature > on right Hand Side Click App Service. and in the popup Click on view estimate.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=app-service

Comment: +1 for the pricing calculator, really nifty

Comment: I like this answer. I was hoping for ranges based on experience rather than just a calculator. This calculator link is helpful because it includes options to ramp up. You seem to assume PaaS where @eric suggests IaaS in his comment. Would you consider adding IaaS and ranges for both based on experience to make this answer more complete?